Use regression to solve for constants of an equation that predicts a variable y
I have variable y with the equation y = a+bln(x). Is it possible to train a regression model in python based on historical data of y to extract the constants of the equation?
So far I’ve tried doing logarithmic regression on the y variable and the x variable but the predictions are not turning out how I expected.

You don't want regression, you want curve fitting. There are a tonnes of examples on the internet for you to check. Start by googling what scipy.optimize.curve_fit does: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Does this answer your question? How to do exponential and logarithmic curve fitting in Python? I found only polynomial fitting

Yes, it is possible to extract the constants of the equation to train the regression-based prediction model based on historical data of x and y. Python does it in the backend and finds the best parameters for the regression model by using optimization techniques(usually it optimizes the cost function using gradient-descent or some other technique).
However, finding out which model to use for prediction will highly depend on what kind of data you have and your goal. Different regression models also take different hyperparameters so we need to apply many techniques like cross-validation and hyperparameter tuning to find the model with the best prediction score. By comparing the best scores for different regression models you can find the best model for your data. However, be wary of the bias-variance tradeoff and always test on different datasets.
